# Python Thread Management Turned Bad

Tags: python, python-3.x, multithreading

I have a rather complex python script that relies on a thread pool and several functions. Here's what the thread pool looks like:

```
threads = list()
threads_aux = {}
thread_count = 3
thread_map = {}

while True:
    for i in range(thread_count):
        if len(threads) <= thread_count and i > (len(threads)-1):
            threads.append(threading.Thread(target=init_bot, args=(i,), name=i) )
            threads_aux[i] = i
            threads[i].start()
            log_info("Started thread " + str(i))
        elif i in threads_aux and not threads[i].is_alive():
            threads[i] = threading.Thread(target=init_bot, args=(i,), name=i)
            threads[i].start()
            log_info("Thread not alive. Started: " + str(i) )

    if thread_count < (len(lay_map)+3):
        thread_count += 1
        log_info(str(len(lay_map))+" layouts. Increased threads by 1")
    sleep(1)
    log_info(str(thread_count)+" threads, "+str(len(thread_map))+" active. Layouts: "+str(len(lay_map)))

    fn = str(Path(__file__).resolve().parent) + '/botThread_kill'
    kill_file = open(fn, 'r')
    killer = int(str.strip(kill_file.read()) )
    if killer == 1:
        log_info("Received manual kill signal. Exiting.", 50)
        os._exit(1)
```

Idle threads poll a server for new jobs (Long-running tasks). When it's given a task, a new empty worker thread is started to take its place so that there are always 3 idle threads waiting to do work. Once it gets to `init_thread`, it polls the server until a job is given and then there is sort of a cascade of functions that get executed until finally, the thread goes into its main work loop (Infinite until killed by a remote user). I haven't included all that code because I don't think its necessary.

Suffice to say, if say, an exception is thrown in a function, it will retry whatever has messed up until it doesn't except. None of that should make a difference though to the main thread pool. After about a day or so of running, sometimes it winds up with no extra worker threads polling for new work. I'm wondering if there's anything in this thread management loop that would cause that. There must be some logical error in the above code.

Here is the `init_bot` function:

```
def init_bot(thread_id):
    global threads, server_num
    options = Options()
    options.add_argument("--headless")
    options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.serviceworker.enabled", False)
    options.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enabled", False)

    gecko_path = '/usr/bin/geckodriver'

    driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=gecko_path, options=options)
    driver.implicitly_wait(30)
    tv_login(driver)
    while True:
        layout_id = tv_load(driver, thread_id)
        if layout_id:
            log_info("Thread "+str(thread_id)+" got layout " + layout_id + ". Passing to monitor.")
            break

        if not check_browser(driver, thread_id):
            log_info("Browser for thread "+str(thread_id)+" is not responding.", 40)
            return False
        sleep(1)
        log_info("Thread "+str(thread_id)+" still in layout loop.")
    tv_monitor(driver, layout_id, thread_id)
```

Comment: All relevant code now there

Comment: When you say "killed by a remote user",  you mean it like that?  I'm asking because you should generally never kill a thread (non-gracefully), because in case it holds a lock at that moment, you're deadlocking.

Comment: @Darkonaut , sorry, no, not that at all. I just meant that each thread manages a resource and if a user deletes that resource, the thread is gracefully released.

Comment: That is done with: `terminate_thread(threads[thread_id])` and `threads.pop(thread_id)` : https://hastebin.com/onudonirum.py

Comment: I wound up refactoring using the newer futures module. If nobody spots anything, I'll answer with what I wound up with.